# Where to find uploaded java code from AWS toolkit for Lambda in AWS Lambda Console

Tags: java, eclipse, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, toolkit

I am using AWS toolkit for lambda, java in eclipse. We do Project->RightClick->Amazon Web Services->Upload/Run. While uploading it asks for the bucket to upload. However, when I go to the console, I do not see teh code. Where can I see the uploaded Lambda code using AWS toolkit for Eclipse. The code runs fine from eclipse and aws console when i test it.

Just curious to know! Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see the zip folder of the code uploaded to your s3 bucket. Also, the function can be viewed under Functions tab of Lambda console.Take care of the regions.